# What should be done about the amazon tag?

Tags: discussion

Is the amazon tag really blacklisted? Can I ask a question with [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon) as a tag?

Comment: Ah, I just realised what you were testing. I see now. My bad. I should have just closed it.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: This has worked out OK as the noredirect=1 [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/286466/what-sould-be-done-about-the-amazon-tag?noredirect=1) allows Jeff to see it complete with the [tag:amazon] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was simply an issue of patience; the blacklist is cached in the appdomain so you have to wait for a build to go out.

A build had not gone out yet, but I just forced one and now it works.

So in the future... patience. :)

Comment: I guess I expected the blacklist to be more dynamic than that. Thanks for the help.